# mallet "import file" use pipe

Tags: import, pipe, mallet

Currently I'm using mallet and when it comes the import of data, I'm fine with import file or import directory according to the APIs or explanations online, but when it comes to the infer-topics part, 
it's said that the new document should be imported using the "input-pipe" options so as to make sure they're using the same alphabet .

It's easy on the command line, but I searched the APIs and wonder where's the code that can link them together?
I mean convert the new document file into mallet format according to the already existed train-samples mallet?

Thanks.